# Объясните как это работает пожалуйста

Tags: php

Есть условная БД - массив. В качестве ключа хранится имя пользователя, в качестве значения хэш пароля. Я помечаю кукой пользователя и теперь хочу проверить есть ли он в БД или нет.  Объясните как в этом случае ведет себя `isset()`? Проверка с помощью конструкции `if` работает, но если я делаю  `var_dump($usersList[$name]);` мне выводится на экран только хэш пароля.

Читал мануал, но все равно не понял. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
function getUsersList(){

    return  [
        'Ivan' => '$2y$10$JRtKotHmvVSh0oJgW1WCTevnk3.ZT4aRWVR5LhyhRBMKBuVbNn6Uy', // 1234
        'Grisha' => '$2y$10$dRHF86JVlGPitSmjNd/W1.oBGQp6DCRn4qvb2Yc6fWZFOkiYGVF/m', // 12346
        'Ira' => '$2y$10$bwfsQ3krdA/wDe0CN8bd0e/nkfYntYeRYezWzGqyVgyMqdvpx8fvK', // 12344
        'Sveta' => '$2y$10$TdJe4UMJOW9XG5P.ZW0ZZ.vEL3S1lSBkLirMlkrGM6QNrImF5yzUO', // 123488
    ];

}

session_start();
setcookie('name', 'Ira');
require_once __DIR__ . '/functions.php';
$name = $_COOKIE['name'];
$usersList = getUsersList();


if(isset($usersList[$name])){
    echo 'Пользователь существет его имя ' . $name;
}else{
    echo 'Пользователя нет в БД';
}

var_dump($usersList[$name]);
```

Comment: а что вы хотите получить кроме хэша пароля, если это и есть значение массива по данному ключу?

Comment: Ничего другого. Мне не понятно, как работает isset($usersList[$name]), то есть как я понимаю, конструкция isset должна в массиве $usersList проверить существует ли элемент с значением  $name.  Но так, как имена указаны в качестве ключей, получается isset проверяет совпадение и в ключах и значениях массива? Верно? Или, может, я что - то не правильно понимаю?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php#refsect1-function.isset-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открываем [мануал](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php#refsect1-function.isset-description) и читаем еще раз:

> Определяет, была ли установлена переменная значением отличным от NULL

Смотрим в вашу конструкцию

```
isset($usersList[$name])
```

Что здесь проверяется исходя из описания метода `isset`? Проверяется, что значение `$usersList[$name]` **отлично от `NULL`**.

Что для этого делается (грубо)? В массиве `$usersList` ищется ключ `$name` и проверяется равно ли **значение** этого ключа `NULL` или нет. Вот и всё.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение, теперь понял.